# Specifying a unicode-named column in dynamic where clause (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity

When I set where clause of a EntityDataSource which contains a unicode column name, this exception occurs:

> The simple identifier 'عنوان_قرارداد'
>   must contain basic Latin characters
>   only. To use UNICODE characters, use
>   an escaped identifier. Near line 6,
>   column 4.

and this is a part of my code:

```
GridDataSource.Where = "it.عنوان_قرارداد == \"something\"";
```

I tried using escaped identifier but this new exception occurred:

> The query syntax is not valid., line
>   6, column 4

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution:

```
GridDataSource.Where = "it.[عنوان_قرارداد] == \"something\"";
```